# Chromium does not start with sandbox on Win 8.1

Tags: windows, google-chrome, chromium

Chromium and Chrome don't start correctly on my computer (Win 8.1).
Whenever I use `chrome.exe` the crash message appears `Chromium has stopped working` with the only option to close the program.
When starting `chrome.exe` again, it launches, but displays only a empty page with
`Aw, snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage`.
If i use `chrome.exe --no-sandbox` it works.

`debug.log` shows this messages continuously:

```
[0801/111006.999:ERROR:process_info.cc(632)] range at 0xea0b1ea200000000, size 0x8c fully unreadable
[0801/111006.999:ERROR:process_info.cc(632)] range at 0xea0b1f0400000000, size 0x8c fully unreadable
[0801/111006.999:ERROR:process_info.cc(632)] range at 0x0, size 0x8c fully unreadable
```

Can somebody plese help me troubleshoot this issue? I suspect it has something to do with my Windows set-up.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove/rename your userdata for chrome
- Find or make a short cut to chrome.  Modify the command to have --no-sandbox
- Run using that command
- Once chrome is up run chrome without the --no-sandbox